# Promise rejected: No provider for a service

Tags: angular

I've developed this `ApiModule` in order to provide services like `UsersService` and `PlansService`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [],
  providers:    [ PlansService, UsersService ]
})
export class ApiModule {
```

I've also created a `CoreModule` like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ApiModule
  ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

which I'm using on `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
```

I'm loading components using a lazy-loading strategy using `RouterModule`. Routes confiration looks like:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'
}, {
    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => System.import('./login/login.module')
  }, { ...
```

So, `LoginModule`:

```
export const routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export default class LoginModule {
```

Nevertheless, I'm getting the message error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for UsersService!

`LoginComponent` is trying to solve an constructor injection:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private commty: UsersService)
    ...
}
```

However, `ApiModule` provides `UsersService`, `ApiModule` is imported in `CoreModule` which is imported in `AppModule`.

Why `LoginModule` is not able to get an `UsersService` instance?

I've also tried to import `CoreModule` into `LoginModule` but it keeps failing.

Comment: try to import CoreModule in LoginModule

Comment: It keeps failing. The same message.

Comment: you don't import `LoginModule` and `CoreModule` in `AppModule` ?

Comment: No, I'm only importing explicitly `CoreModule`. `LoginModule` is loaded my `RouterModule`...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include `ApiModule` through `CoreModule`, you will need to export from `CoreModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ApiModule
  ],
 exports: [
   ApiModule
 ]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

which really makes this a [shared module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module). 
You will have to probably import `CoreModule` in `LoginModule` as well.This will be contrary to your lazy loading strategy though. You need to go through the section **Why UserService isn't shared** in the link.
It specifies:

> Do not specify app-wide singleton providers in a shared module. A
>   lazy-loaded module that imports that shared module makes its own copy
>   of the service.

Comment: It keeps failing. Do I need to add `exports: [ UsersService ]` on `ApiModule` as well?

Comment: Let me ask you for a related question. Sometimes I've seen modules declaring that provides a service (or anything) but they don't export each provided one in `exports`. Why do I need to export them?

Comment: No you dont need to export the service. sry..my bad. you are getting the same error?

Comment: Or directly import ApiModule instead of going through the coreModule?

Comment: I've set `UsersService` in exports. Angular tells me `UsersService` is not declared or imported in `ApiModule`. I've set `UsersService` in `declarations` but I'm getting an `Unexpected value 'UsersService' declared by the module 'ApiModule'`. I'm really struggling with this issue. I'm failing to figure out what do I need to export, import, declare...

Comment: dont set it in exports..I think you should directly import ApiModule as it is providing services.

Comment: Nothing works. I've tried to import `ApiModule` on `LoginModule` directly. I've tried to import `CoreModule` on `LoginModule`...